# Inaccurate information on multi-city search on Kayak

Tags: air-travel, bookings, fares

For the coming week, I am searching for flights out of either Ottawa, Montreal or Toronto going to any of the major cities in India (Bombay, Delhi, Bangalore).

Kayak allows you to search for the best fares for multiple cities in one go.

In going so, I'm finding a discrepancy in the price that Kayak is giving me versus the actual price shown on the airlines website.

For example, here is the search I am doing:

[image]

I choose the third option ($2186) and after I am transferred to the Turkish Airlines website, I see this:

[image]

As can be seen, the price shown on the Turkish website is almost double that of the price shown on Kayak. Turkish Airlines is not the only airline that I've seen this happen with.

How do I go about finding that same fare on the Turkish website? Or is Kayak actually giving me information that is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Kayak's help page on prices](http://www.kayak.com/k/feedback/form?i=price):

> Although we try hard to find accurate prices, sometimes we don't.
>   Fill out the form below, and it will alert our programmers so they can
>   investigate the problem. With your help, search results will get
>   better for everyone.

Kayak is not a perfectly 'live' search site. It's as close to live as they can manage, but prices do change all the time, and they could either hit all the airlines' sites every 5 minutes for every possible flight, seat, class and leg and combination, or they can provide ranges, estimates and updates 'regularly', if not via an API.

Also, some airlines don't include all their charges (credit card etc) in Kayak. RyanAir flights, for example, are notorious for this.

Long story short, Kayak is a pretty reliable guide, and some flights these days are even bookable without leaving kayak's website, but they're not perfect.

Comment: Kayak knows about charges for credit cards that arise on different reservation sites (independently from the airlines). These charges are listed separately from the price of the flight tickets. For a reason or another they keep them separate. Not very transparent and even a little bit perfidious ...

Comment: My understanding is that airlines publish their prices on Kayak ([eg this article about RyanAir joining them](http://www.tnooz.com/2010/01/20/news/ryanair-in-shock-move-as-it-agrees-fares-deal-with-kayak/)), and therefore it would be the airlines' responsibility to provide accurate prices. Indeed, given that there are different charges for different cards, how would Kayak be able to show that?

Comment: Kayak shows prices for the different sites where you can book the flights. In my case, seat24 comes up very often with the lowest price. However, they have a pretty high "credit card" fee. At the end it is not significantly cheaper than e.g expedia or the airline itself. Now kayak lists these extra fees, but does not integrate them into the final price. They still continue to lure travelers by displaying low prices, and then you get the surprise.

Comment: The separate display of the extra fees seems to be only a feature of the German version. In other versions, such as .com or .fr they even do not show them. But my main point remains. THE PRICES AT KAYAK ARE NOT NECESSARY THE FINAL PRICES, AS SOME FEES MAY BE ADDED. THEY DO NOT DEPEND ON THE AIRLINE, BUT ON THE SITE WHERE THE FLIGHT IS BOOKED.

Comment: This being said, there may be other airline specific costs for extras. And even this is not confined to low-cost carriers such as Ryanair. Other carriers have similar policies